# Display photo from Active Directory in an access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory

I'd like to display the photo of the logged in user from Active Directory in an Access form.  Is there a way to do this using VBA? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TesterUserPic()
    Debug.Print UserNameToPic("jdoe")
    Debug.Print UserNameToPic("jblow")
End Sub

'return the path to the user's pic so it can be loaded into the form...
Function UserNameToPic(id As String) As String
    Const FPATH As String = "C:\_Stuff\Test\"
    Dim FSO, f, rootDSE, base, fltr, scope, attr
    Dim conn, rs, cmd

    Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    base = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"

    'filter on user objects with the given account name
    fltr = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)"
    fltr = fltr & "(sAMAccountName=" & id & "))"
    attr = "thumbnailPhoto"
    scope = "subtree"

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        SaveBinaryData FPATH & id & ".jpg", rs(0).Value
        UserNameToPic = FPATH & id & ".jpg"
    End If

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Function

Sub BinaryDataToFile(FileName, ByteArray)
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    If IsNull(ByteArray) Then Exit Sub

    Dim BinaryStream 'Create Stream object
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With BinaryStream
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write ByteArray
        .SaveToFile FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End With
End Sub
```